# How to intersect two classes as base class for extended class in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, constructor, casting, extends

I need to create HOF (Higher order function) which will modify/add property to prototype of provided class. Is it even possible?

```
interface IStore {
  new (): {};
}

interface IWatchable {
  new() : {
    watch: boolean;
  };
}

const Store = <T extends IStore>(clazz: T): T & IWatchable => {
  return class extends clazz {
    watch = true;
  };
};

 class X extends Store(class {})
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
//              Base constructors must all have the same return type.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do mixins, this is the pattern that will work (as per [this PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13743)):

```
interface IStore {
    new(...a: any[]): {}; 
}

const Store = <T extends IStore>(clazz: T) => {
    return class extends clazz {
        watch = true;
    };
};

class X extends Store(class { }) { }
```

This should give you what you want, you can have the `IWatchable` interface, and the mixin classes will be assignable to it even if the return of `Store` function does not explicitly implement the interface (the miracle of structural typing)

```
interface IWatchable {
    new(): {
        watch: boolean;
    };
}
let w : IWatchable = X //ok
```